# LM 20 Win 10 dual boot going read-only and corrupting filesystem

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, root-filesystem, corruption

I've been having trouble with my dual boot (win 10/LM20) install that are just driving me crazy.

Here's a summary of the diagnosis I've made so far

- Install windows 10 making a partition for Linux from win installer.
- Windows boots just fine. I've run the HD integrity tests inside windows and it says the HD is healthy.
- Proceed to install linux. The installer doesn't always work and my research suggested it had to do with my Nvidia card. Setting the nomodeset option solves the issue, installer runs just fine.
- Created three partitions inside free space at the end of my HD:
  [/dev/sda5] Swap (primary, use as swap area),
  [/dev/sda6] Root (primary, ext4, mount point: /),
  [/dev/sda7] Home (primary, ext4, mount point: /home)
- Installation runs smoothly.
- After install, the startup crashes and just halts the computer. Assumed same Nvidia issues and modified the startup script in the Grub menu to include the nomodeset option. Startup ok.
- Inside the SO, apply updates through the update manager and reboot
- Reboot runs nicely (no need to add nomodeset)
- Work for some time, if I want to install software or apply updates, my filesystem goes into read-only mode
- Rebooting makes the system go into initramfs prompt, making a fsck on my root partition solves the issue temporally in some cases, in others it just corrupts the entire partition, cannot even login using the gui

Turned off fast boot from windows partiton, removed metadata_csum and 64bit flags on the /dev/sda6 from a live usb, secure boot disabled. I'm just so sick of reinstalling, if someone could help me diagnose or figure this thing out, it'd be really appreciated.

Comment: What brand/model system? Are  you installing the correct nVidia driver? And if changing driver, purging old before installing new? Once nvidia driver installed, then nomodeset should not be used.  Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, the SSD firmware? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks for responding, its a gamer laptop MSI gf63 8rd. In previous attempts I installed the recommended driver, but in my last attempt I just leaved the open source one that was installed with the initial update (the startup log never complained) no need to nomodeset. How could I update UEFI? also no SSD. Let me come back to you with the summary report

Comment: Alright since last install attempt failed I made a fresh install. Right after installation finished (no updates applied) ran boot summary report from a Boot-Repair live USB. Paste bin to the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/C2qrcN8QY8/

Comment: Install looks normal. MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061109/dual-boot-windows-10-cannot-boot-latest-ubuntu-but-only-older-versions To update UEFI, you need to go to MSI support page for updated driver. UEFI may be called BIOS still.

Comment: Installed latest bios from the MSI site for my laptop from here: https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GF63-8RD disabled fast boot from bios (didn't realize it was enabled from bios). Proceeding to install updates and Nvidia private driver. I’ll try my LM installation and come back to this thread if some development occurs

Comment: Update: applied updates, installed private nvidia driver and been working on linux for a couple hours. Then shut down the system completely and restarted. It boots on the grub> prompt asking me to manually load the kernel. Running the boot-repair and making diagnostics gives the following report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MMydWmy7pk/

Comment: Another update: just noticed in bios the secure mode and fast boot option are enabled again. I have no idea what could have enable them

Comment: Windows updates turns fast start up back on in Windows. And an UEFI update often resets many UEFI settings to defaults. Windows may also schedule an UEFI update with some systems. Often the Windows updates are just in the back ground, and I think they have made it more difficult or impossible to manually schedule/run the updates.

Comment: Apparently windows didnt rewrite the UEFI settings. Tried a linux 19.2 with older kernel and every reboot asked me to do a fsck. Assumed the problem was windows mismanaging ext4 filesystem so i went live usb and disabled metadata_csum and 64bit flags with tune2fs. Rebooted into kernel panic. This is getting on my nerves, I was always able to have dual boot so I can only assume a recent windows patch is doing something to my linux partition.

Comment: I have never reset anything with tune2fs. Only used to to review some settings.